# Handler() delay not working on my custom writing text animation

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-animation

I'm trying to append "..." to my `TextView` in the form of:

1. append "."
2. 2000ms delay
3. append "."
4. 2000ms delay
5. append "..."

However when I run my app, it appends all 3 "..." at the same time.

**GlobalFunctions.kt**

```
fun writeText(tv: TextView, s: String){
    fun write(letter: Char){
        Handler().postDelayed({tv.append(letter.toString())}, 2000)
    }
    for (letter in s){
        write(letter)
    }
}
```

**Activity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    writeText(chosenPlayer, "...")
}
```

**xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chosenPlayer"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:text=""
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorGreen"
    android:textSize="30dp"/>
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: You are appending all 3 dots at the same time then you wait your 2 seconds

Comment: How is that possible if my delay is in `write()`?

Comment: use `2000 * (i + 1)` and pass `i` as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc

Comment: I'm abit confused what you mean by as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4? @pskink

Comment: `fun write(letter: Char, i: int) {...`

Comment: getting this error: https://i.imgur.com/g57mUA8.png @pskink

Comment: so use long, as they say

Comment: I've fixed that - just not sure how the `i` value is meant to change and how it would actually make the animation work if it did change.

Comment: when calling `write` pass not only your char but also a long varaible that increments starting from `0` - like `write(letter, someLongCounter++)`

Comment: Thankyou! It works great. However are you able to explain to me why my first function didn't work? There should be a `2000ms` delay after each time `write()` is called.

Comment: use `Log.d` to print the delay you are passing to `postDelayed` method

Comment: @Zorgan your first function didn't work because the delay is on printing the value from the point you call the function. so assume that for loop executes and first iteration write method is called at 1ms. And what you are doing is telling the handler to execute at 2001ms(after 2000ms). and Second iteration write method called at 2 ms and what you are doing  is telling the handler to delay 2000ms from 2ms so it executes at 2002ms. Like this way all dots got printed immediately just after 2000ms. Hope this helps.